# make all string to lowercase with function

Tags: python, pandas

So I have this datafram **df** with two columns:

```
column1    column2
2017       BUTTERSCOOP
2016       likeheLL
```

and I want to make all the characters in column2 to be lower with this function:

```
def lowerCase(text, field1, field2):
    text = text[[field1, field2]]
    text[field1] = text[field1].str.lower()
    text[field2] = text[field2].str.lower()
    text = text
    result = text
    return result
```

and I call the function with this code:

```
df= lowerCase(df, 'column1', 'column2')
```

but I got this error message:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

anyone might want to help me what's problem with my function? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to apply this function on column1 which contains int values, not string... try to use the lowercase only for column2

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
df['column2'].str.lower()
```